# Is it possible to mark the message thread with 'unseen=0'?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I work on Google Chrome extension for facebook.

I have a button and if you click on it, a popup with latest active threads appears. I want to say to facebook server that no threads are 'unseen' afterwards. So that the messages jewel on Facebook main page will show no notifications.

Can I do this with Graph API? POST calls to graph.facebook.com/thread_id with unseen=0 don't work.

Alternatives?

Comment: Why would you even want this?

Comment: This is to mark inbox latest messages as seen when user opens popup with last threads' messages. The number for badge on a browser action icon is fetched from fb graph api and equals to total 'unseen' count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have write access to the inbox.  Only read access `read_mailbox`.  Sorry, but that's the only permission that Facebook currently has available.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

However, you can keep track of the inbox items on a remote server's data store and have your plugin query that to know what's been "seen". So at least from your plugin's perspective, things are showing up correctly.

Comment: Our competitor browser Rockmelt made it work. And I think it's the case described in your last paragraph.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the feedback on my answer.  It's hard to toubleshoot from afar and knowing we steer people in the right direction is always nice.